# JS Promises - Again - Can I Add Promise To Anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Another JS Promises question. I'm understanding the states however I still haven't completely grasped one thing:

So:

- Can I create promises with any object? Or does the object I'm creating on need to support it?
- If everything does support it, then can I use the `then` construct however and where I wish e.g. - is the code below valid?
- If it does not support it then i have to use some sort of library like Bluebird?

So is this valid:

```
getScrollableHeight() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
      var height = browser.execute(function () {
         return document.body.scrollHeight
      })
      resolve(height.value)
      });
 }
```

Comment: I found this Promises guide to be very helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense, and is invalid too.  What is `res`, and you have a return before your fulfill, so will never get called anyway.

Comment: If `browser.execute` is asynchronous, then you want your fulfill inside the callback.  So instead of `return document.body.scrollheight`, it's just `fulfill(document.body.scrollHeight)`,  also can you use the normal `resolve, reject`.. too many `l's`..for me..

Comment: @Keith - sorry meant to ask is it in the fulfill we return the answer we want?

Comment: Post the sequence of events you want, so I can see. You can probably ditch the second return and put `fulfull(document.body.scrollHeight)` inside `.execute()`. I will try and reply a solid example shortly once I get a couple minutes.

Comment: That's correct,  normally we use `resolve` and `reject`, but you can name them what you want..  `resolve` is to return the value, `reject` if there was an error.

Comment: I was going to say exactly what Keith just said also. It almost looked like my initial comment somehow sent.

Comment: Yeah, I'm watching you.. :)

Comment: I suddenly got PTSD like maybe `fulfill` is ok and some people use it, because technically you can use anything as long as it matches the first, second parameter.

Comment: Note that the `browser.execute` is actually something from WebDriverIO - that allows me to run some JS code directly in the browser - so unsure if I can have the resolve within there
http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html

Comment: That looks like a callback, so your fine.  Callbacks are executed from the sender..  Actually scrap that, just looking at the docs now..  Seems like this function is called sync, anyway.. So no promises needed.

Comment: @Keith so in my updated code above - I understand how the last resolve is the promise - however where is teh promise that the `browser.execute` actually got the value for `height`

Comment: You can always wrap functions in a Promise return. It is amazingly awesome for handling callbacks inside the function that take their sweet time. It's all about the subsequent handling which involves `.then()` and `.catch()` which handle your `resolve` and `reject` conditions. Thens and Catches can be chained. I'm still on the phone but I will write you a series of illustrative examples after. I may even show you async/await if you can handle it.

Comment: @agm1984 - could you give an example - i really can't picture it :)

Comment: I will just wait a few mins. I will type you an epic sampler pack.

Comment: @agm1984 - not that everything that happens inside WDIO's `browser.execute` is syncronous - the result just takes a second to get to me - its just that I need to wait for 
So at the moment I'm using a browser.pause(1000) - but I dont want to do that
`getScrollableHeight() {
    var height = browser.execute(function () {
      return document.body.scrollHeight
    })
    browser.pause(1000)
    return height.value
  }`

Comment: When you call `getScrollableHeight()`, you can access the value of `resolve(height.value)`, by doing `getScrollableHeight().then(function(value) { console.log(value) })`